# Excel Sumproduct counts rows incorrectly with multiple column criteria

Tags: excel

I am trying to calculate Precision and Recall for the output of a model which makes 3 predictions whether a person's name is John or not.
The ground truth for each entry/row is column A. The predictions are stored in columns O,Q and S. The model only needs 2 out of 3 predictions to be > 50% each to be considered correct.

Therefore a True Positive is when >=2 of O,Q,S are > 50%.
Similarly, a False Negative is when < 2 of O,Q,S are > 50%.

```
Precision = TP / (TP + FP)
Recall = TP / (TP + FN)
```

I can calculate precision ok because the final logic operator is >= and therefore the values cannot be 0 to be counted.  But for this, the final SUM in the denominator is problematic, counting all rows.

This is the part that works, the Precision:

```
SUM(IF((A2:A300="John")*((O2:O300>=.5)+(Q2:Q300>=.5)+(S2:S300>=.5))>=2,1)) / (SUM(IF((A2:A300="John")*((O2:O300>=.5)+(Q2:Q300>=.5)+(S2:S300>=.5))>=2,1)) + (SUM(IF((A2:A300="Not John")*((O2:O300>=.5)+(Q2:Q300>=.5)+(S2:S300>=.5))>=2,1)))
```

And this is what I'm trying but doesn't work.  The last < operator screws up the denominator and I can't figure out how to fix:

```
SUM(IF((A2:A300="John")*((O2:O300>=.5)+(Q2:Q300>=.5)+(S2:S300>=.5))>=2,1)) / (SUM(IF((A2:A300="John")*((O2:O300>=.5)+(Q2:Q300>=.5)+(S2:S300>=.5))>=2,1)) + (SUM(IF((A2:A300="John")*((O2:O300>=.5)+(Q2:Q300>=.5)+(S2:S300>=.5))<2,1)))
```

If there are 3 rows where A = "John" with only 2 of those rows have 2 of O,Q,S > 50%
And if there are 3 rows where A = "Not John" with all 3 rows have O,Q,S > 50%
Then,

```
Precision = 2 / (2 + 3) = 2/5
Recall = 2 / (2 + 1) = 2/3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the recall by putting an extra set of brackets round the <2 comparison:

```
=SUM(IF((A2:A7="John")*((O2:O7>=0.5)+(Q2:Q7>=0.5)+(S2:S7>=0.5))>=2,1))/(SUM(IF((A2:A7="John")*((O2:O7>=0.5)+(Q2:Q7>=0.5)+(S2:S7>=0.5))>=2,1))+(SUM(IF((A2:A7="John")*(((O2:O7>=0.5)+(Q2:Q7>=0.5)+(S2:S7>=0.5))<2),1))))
```

so you avoid multiplying by zero for the 'Not John'  rows before doing the comparison and get the correct denominator.

[image]